# jQuery addClass targeting element but not adding the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have the following code.

```js
$("#duration").on("click", function() {
  $('#duration .select-selected').addClass('select-arrow-active');
  $('#duration .select-items').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 custom-select" id="duration">
  <p class="label-title">How much time do you have?</p>
  <label for="duration">
    <select name="duration" class="passes-buscador-select">
     <option value="">NOT SURE </option>
     <option value="less-than-1-week"> Less than 1 week </option>
     <option value="1-week-to-2-weeks"> 1 week to 2 weeks </option>
     <option value="more-than-2-weeks"> More than 2 weeks </option>
     <option value="daytrips">  Day trips </option>
    </select>
   </label>
  <div class="select-selected">NOT SURE </div>
  <div class="select-items select-hide">
    <div> Less than 1 week </div>
    <div> 1 week to 2 weeks </div>
    <div> More than 2 weeks </div>
    <div> Day trips </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the user clicks the element the class is not added, after checking it with the inspector I noticed the element blinks which means is being targeted properly more so when I execute.

```
$('#duration .select-selected').addClass('select-arrow-active');
```

On the console the class gets added, so I have no idea what could be happening. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please could you post your HTML too? That would make it easier to understand what might be going on.

Comment: Add a simple `console.log("click")` inside the event handler, it sounds like it's getting called twice or not at all.

Comment: Is your `#duration` added later on, i.e. after the `.on("click")` code has run?

Comment: Please include a [mre] of the issue. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: Try to recreate the problem in a snippet within the question.  This will help us to see what it is doing and will help you - in the process of recreating this here, you may find it works here - so there's something else causing the problem.  We can't help you if it's something you don't mention in the question.  Have a read of [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for adding the HTML @isaac - I must admit I can't see the problem you're describing, but I'm a bit unsure what you're trying to achieve. I've created a jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/tjh12345/352z8nLm/ - does this have the incorrect behaviour in it? If it does, please can you add more information about what's wrong with it? If that jsfiddle works correctly, then you know the problem is in some other code that you haven't posted. Hope this helps!

Comment: You have not included the CSS either, and it's likely adding the class does something noticeable that we're supposed to see. [Edit] your question, click "edit this snippet" and add the relevant CSS to the CSS box. Click Tidy to ensure the code is formatted well, then click Save and Insert.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**:

I created a snipet with a CSS class editing the element's color, showing that the class is being added. Look:

```js
$("#duration").on("click", function() {
  $('#duration .select-selected').addClass('select-arrow-active');
  $('#duration .select-items').toggle();
});
```

```css
#duration .select-selected {
  color: blue;
}

#duration .select-selected.select-arrow-active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 custom-select" id="duration">
  <p class="label-title">How much time do you have?</p>
  <label for="duration">
    <select name="duration" class="passes-buscador-select">
     <option value="">NOT SURE </option>
     <option value="less-than-1-week"> Less than 1 week </option>
     <option value="1-week-to-2-weeks"> 1 week to 2 weeks </option>
     <option value="more-than-2-weeks"> More than 2 weeks </option>
     <option value="daytrips">  Day trips </option>
    </select>
   </label>
  <div class="select-selected">NOT SURE </div>
  <div class="select-items select-hide">
    <div> Less than 1 week </div>
    <div> 1 week to 2 weeks </div>
    <div> More than 2 weeks </div>
    <div> Day trips </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is already an element with `id="duration"` - it's the top level `div` in the posted HTML. (I'm not sure exactly what Isaac is trying to achieve so I don't know if it's in the right place or not.)

Comment: I'm teying to  add  the class "select-arrow-active" to the element "select-selected" inside the #duration structure, as i saud before it works on the console but not in the document.

Comment: That's already the existing behaviour. I've updated my jsfiddle to make it more obvious - https://jsfiddle.net/tjh12345/352z8nLm/2/

Comment: you are right, Tim. I had not noticed this element. And the behavior is already occurring as Isaac wishes.

Comment: Yes thanks @Tim it does what it should thats the issue in my production site it doesn't, it could be happening some other element is rewriting the element? how can i debug that?

Comment: If the code that you've posted is all working correctly, then I'm not sure anyone here will be able to help you I'm afraid. We can only work with the information you're able to give us. You're right that there must be some other code which is affecting the behaviour, but without being able to see the code I don't think we can really help you fix this issue. Feel free to ask another question though if you manage to find other code which is changing the behaviour, and need help working with it.

Comment: Isaac, can you share with us the link to the production site? We can try to see through the chrome inspect if there is any other bind modifying this element, or something else that is visible in the loaded CSS and JS files